# Ipython: same source behave differently

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I run the following code on Ipython:

```
import tensorflow as tf

X=[1.,2.,3.]
Y=[1.,2.,3.]
m=len(X)

W=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

hypothesis=tf.mul(W, X)
cost=tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(hypothesis-Y,2))/(m)

init=tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

W_val=[]
cost_val=[]

for i in range(-30,50):
    xPos=i*0.1
    yPos=sess.run(cost,feed_dict={W:xPos})
    print('{:3.1f}, {:3.1f}'.format(xPos, yPos))
```

Once it prints out

```
-3.0, -3.0
-2.9, -2.9
-2.8, -2.8
-2.7, -2.7
-2.6, -2.6
-2.5, -2.5
-2.4, -2.4
-2.3, -2.3
-2.2, -2.2
-2.1, -2.1
-2.0, -2.0
-1.9, -1.9
-1.8, -1.8
-1.7, -1.7
-1.6, -1.6
-1.5, -1.5
-1.4, -1.4
-1.3, -1.3
-1.2, -1.2
-1.1, -1.1
-1.0, -1.0
-0.9, -0.9
-0.8, -0.8
-0.7, -0.7
.....
```

The output is wrong and I couldn't figure it out.
I opened a new notebook and copy and paste the same code. Now it works fine:

```
-3.0, 74.7
-2.9, 71.0
-2.8, 67.4
-2.7, 63.9
-2.6, 60.5
-2.5, 57.2
-2.4, 53.9
-2.3, 50.8
-2.2, 47.8
-2.1, 44.8
-2.0, 42.0
-1.9, 39.2
-1.8, 36.6
-1.7, 34.0
-1.6, 31.5
```

Both notebook are in the same folder and they use the same kernel. I restarted the kernel for both notebook several times, but the output is still different. How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was GPU memory issue. I was running other tensorflow source which used most of GPU memory. When it is short of memory the calculation is not done.